# Django: 1.5: Overriding generic.DetailView returns 404

Tags: django, django-views

I have a generic.DetailView which I'm trying to override the function get_queryset(self)  I'm doing the following:

```
class MyView(generic.DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    slug_field='guid'
    template_name = 'myhtml.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        guid = uuid.UUID(self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        x = MyModel.objects.all().filter(guid=guid)
        pprint(x)
        return MyModel.objects.all().filter(guid=guid)
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url (r'^(?P<slug>[A-Fa-f0-9]{30,32})$', view.MyView.as_view(), name='myview'),
```

)

When I run the page, I keep getting a 404 error.  However, I know MyModel returns something because pprint returns:

```
[<MyModel: mydata>]
```

PS  If I do this same modification w/ PK:  I still get a 404:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=pk)

...and I know MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=pk) returns data
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `404` because `get_object()` is run right after `get_queryset()`, which filters the queryset again (using slug url kwarg), giving you no results.

You should instead override `get_object()` method and return a single object.

Something like this should work:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None)
    guid = uuid.UUID(slug)
    return queryset.get(guid=guid)
```

**NOTE:**
This is just a quick example, you should definitely look into original `get_object()` method and see how to handle all the edge cases and exceptions.